# How to import non-text data from std input in a Mathematica script?

Tags: import, scripting, free-form-input

Or maybe a better question is - how can I get a `stdin` stream? I need to run on Linux.

I did look at [Reading from STDIN, or: how to pipe data into Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3425/reading-from-stdin-or-how-to-pipe-data-into-mathematica), but that talks about text data. I need to import an image, sent to standard output by another program.

According to Mathematica documentation, there is no pre-defined standard input stream, there's only `$Output`, which is standard output, and `$Input`, which is the script being executed. There are only 2 functions that read from standard input in the expected way - `Input`, which tries to read a Mathematica expression, and `InputString`, which tries to read a string till it gets a newline. Neither of these is good for reading non-text data.

What I would prefer to do is read from a stream, preferably using `Import`. I want to use this Mathematica script in a shell script, and pipe data to it.

I tried `Import[OpenRead["/dev/stdin"]]`, but this only seems to work if I have an actual file on disk and I redirect input using `<`. It doesn't work if I pipe data to the Mathematica script.

Comment: tough one.. you can call InputString in a loop but I dont think you can discern whether each string was terminated by a newline, eof, etc..

Comment: Exactly. :( Mathematica's so powerful, it's a pity that this one thing is so difficult.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out if you run an exteral process *it* gets stdin..

```
img=Import["!python readstdin.py","tiff"];
Print[Dimensions[ImageData[img]]];
```

where my python script is just this:

```
import sys
print sys.stdin.read()
```

seems to work:

```
math -script script.m < file.tiff
(* {900,1200,3} *)
```

Edit .. even better..:

```
img=Import["!cat -","tiff"];
```

Comment: Actually if you call `cat` without any argument, it also copies stdin to stdout. So you can just omit the `-` and write `img=Import["!cat","tiff"]`.

Comment: Wow, the only solution is to run another process? :) I guess I'll accept it if there's no other way.

Comment: @george2079 How would you do this on windows without python installed?

Comment: You could install CoreUtils for Windows, which has `cat`, or maybe use `type`, if it can direct everything from its std input to its std output.