# How do I evaluate Mathematica expressions and insert them in a LaTeX file?

Tags: interoperability, latex

I want to make use of *Mathematica* as the backend to solve some computations used in my LaTeX input file. As I have  no knowledge to make it in *Mathematica*, I used Maxima as explained in the following steps that I got somewhere on the internet.

### Step 1

Download and install Maxima.

### Step 2

Create a batch file named `cas.bat` (for example) as follows.

```sh
rem cas.bat
echo off
set PATH=%PATH%;"C:\Program Files (x86)\Maxima-5.31.2\bin"
maxima --very-quiet -r %1 > solution.tex
```

Save the batch in the same directory in which your input file below exists. It is just for the sake of simplicity.

### Step 3

Create the input file named `main.tex` (for example) as follows.

```tex
% main.tex
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\f(#1){(#1)^2-5*(#1)+6}


\begin{document} 

\section{Problem}
Evaluate $\f(x)$ for $x=\frac 1 2$.

\section{Solution}
\immediate\write18{cas "x: 1/2;tex(\f(x));"}

\input{solution}

\end{document}
```

### Step 4

Compile the input file with `pdflatex -shell-escape main` and you will get a nice output as follows.

[image]

### Questions

Apparently the output of Maxima is as follows. I don't know how to make it cleaner.

```
solution.tex

                                       1
                                       -
                                       2
$${{15}\over{4}}$$
                                     false
```

Now, my questions are

- how to implement the scenario above in *Mathematica*?
- if *Mathematica* also produces the unnecessary texts, how to remove such texts?
- if *Mathematica* also produces the same output format, how to obtain just `\frac{15}{4}` without `$$...$$`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is a good application for the highly underused [`Splice`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Splice.html) function which has been in *Mathematica* since version 1 (I don't recall it ever being used on this site).

1. Create a file called `main.mtex` with the following text:

   ```tex
   \documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
   \usepackage{amsmath}
   \def\f(#1){(#1)^2-5*(#1)+6}
   \begin{document}

   \section{Problem}
   Evaluate $\f(x)$ for $x=\frac 1 2$.

   \section{Solution}
   $ <* f[x_] := x^2 - 5 x + 6; f[1/2] *> $
   \end{document}
   ```

   Everything you want *Mathematica* to evaluate should be written between `<* *>`.
2. In *Mathematica*, run `Splice["main.mtex"]` (replace with the correct path to your file). The `Splice` function reads the file and replaces the text between `<* *>` with its *Mathematica* output. The default output for input files with the extension `.mtex` is `TeXForm`, which mostly does a good job of translating to LaTeX for non-complicated expressions.
3. Compile the `main.tex` file that is created as an output of `Splice`.

   [image]

---

Rather than using a TeX macro to expand the equation, I would suggest using *Mathematica* here as well. Here's a modified example:

```tex
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% <* f[x_] := x^2 - 5 x +6 *>
\begin{document}
\section{Problem}
Evaluate $ <* f[x] *> $ for $x=\frac 1 2$.

\section{Solution}
$$ <* f[1/2] *> $$

\end{document}
```

The definition `f[x_]` will be available to *Mathematica* throughout the splice operation and we can use this to make the text replacement as well. I think it would be a much simpler solution than hacking something together with TeX/interpreting the macro in *Mathematica*. Note that I commented out the `f[x_]` definition in TeX, because *Mathematica* outputs `Null` for that operation, which gets inserted as `\text{Null}` and we don't want that. The result is the same (perhaps better than using the TeX macro):

[image]

Comment: Perhaps not here, but http://stackoverflow.com/a/1688457/353410

Comment: @DonutE.Knot You can create a `MathematicaScript`. I don't have the time to do this now, but you can look at questions and answers here using this. [How to use Mathematica functions in Python programs?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4673) and [Reading from STDIN, or: how to pipe data into Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3439) might be of use.

Comment: How to show `*` for multiplication in `x^2 -5 x+6` produced by `Splice`? Some plotting macros (PSTricks) need the `*`.

Comment: Underused indeed. I do not recall ever having used it, but it is a very good match for this question. +1!

Comment: +1 for a very useful post. As of Version 10 `Splice` has been superseded by [`FileTemplate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FileTemplate.html?q=FileTemplate) as the documentation tells me.

Comment: Could you explain how to use `FileTemplate` in spite of `Splice` that has been superseded?